# Array updates all its its elements on reading the State in React - Typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, state, setstate

I am developing an app about trips, with a set of waypoints. I defined trips just with two waypoints:

```
interface Waypoint{
    lat: string,
    lon: string,
    displayName: string,
    departureDate: string;
  }
interface Trip{
    tripId: string;
    waypoints: Waypoint[];
    completed: boolean;
  }
constructor(props: PropsType) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // other state variables
      trip: {
        waypoints: [{lat:'', lon:'', displayName:'', departureDate: ''},
                    {lat:'', lon:'', displayName:'', departureDate: ''}],
        tripId: this.props.location.state.trip.id || '',
        completed: this.props.location.state.trip.completed || false,
      },
    };
  }
```

On updating the state field `this.state.trip.waypoints[i].address` if I use the `.map()` method all fields are updated whereas when I look for an specific index just that index is updated. `input` parameter is the text content in the input field. Lets say I write "berlin" in the input field:

```
handleInputChange = (input: string, index: number = 0) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        console.log('init: ', prevState.trip.waypoints)
        const wps = prevState.trip.waypoints.map((wp, i) => {
            console.log('string ' + i.toString(), wp.displayName)
            if (index === i) {
              wp.displayName = input;
              return wp;
            } else {
              return wp;
            }
          });
      console.log('stateWps: ', wps)
      return { 
        trip: {
          ...prevState.trip,
          waypoints: wps,
        }
      };
    });
}
```

Has this effect on writting the last letter, in all cases both waypoints are updated:

[image]

Reading the state.trip updates all the waypoints before enetring the `.map()` method. Updating the first array index automatically updates the second one. However if I update the state in the following manner I do not have this behaviour:

```
handleInputChange = (input: string, index: number = 0) => {
    const wps = [...this.state.trip.waypoints];
    wps[index] = {...wps[index], displayName: input};
    this.setState({
      trip: {
        ...this.state.trip,
        waypoints: wps
      }
    }, () => {
      console.log('stateWps ', this.state.trip.waypoints)
    })
}
```

Yields this output:

[image: ArrayIndex]

How can be the first `handleInputChange` function be re-written to update the `state.trip.waypoints` using the `.map()` method? Thanks

Update:

I do not think the prblem should be here since using the other way it is working as expected, it is when using prevState and the `.map()` method that it updates all the `waypoints.displayName fields` even when I hard-code the `0` value in the function call. Just in case you find anything.
The component handling the input:

```
<AutosuggestInput
    placeholder="Trip Origin"
    value={this.state.trip.waypoints[0].displayName}
    suggestions={places}
    onValueChange={(input: string) => {
        this.handleInputChange(input, 0);
    }}
/>
```

class AutosuggestInput extends React.Component<Props, State>:

```
onInputHandler = (event: FormEvent<any>, {newValue, method}: {newValue: string; method: string}) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.onValueChange(newValue);
  };

...

render() {

const { value, suggestions, placeholder } = this.props;

const inputProps = {
  placeholder: placeholder ? placeholder : '',
  value: value ? value : '',
  onChange: this.onInputHandler
};

return (
  <Autosuggest
    suggestions={suggestions}
    onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
    onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
    getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
    renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
    inputProps={inputProps}
  />
);
```

}

I am using react-autosuggest: https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest

Comment: You want to get the state updated only for that waypoint whose index matches using the map function?

Comment: right, only update the matching index, in this example to illustrate the case I wrote it to be 0.

Comment: Can you post the Html code where you are calling the handleInputChange function.?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox, since it the first image your init log shows both displayname to be berlin, but the consecutive log shows berli and berlin. Also, if all the init log was already updated, how are you differentiating between the init and stateMap log?

Comment: it is already initiated because there is a log for every change made, that is for every written letter, berli & berli are for each waypoint. It seems it is executed synchronously but by the time the state is updated for the first item it updates both

Comment: I think the key is in destructuring the array, when I type let wp = {...wps[index]};` then it works, if its not enclosed in a destructured object then both waypoints are updated